# Unable to show satisfaction of assumptions for a Linear Mixed Model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I conducted a virtual reality study in which the test persons had to select objects with different forms of interaction. I varied the object size, the object density and the distance to the object. I measured the time and the number of missed selections. I use linear mixed models for the evaluation because not every test person used every form of interaction and not every form of interaction supports every scenario (for example, some forms of interaction only work at short distances). This works fine for the measured time but now I have a problem with the number of missed selections. I am not able to show that the assumptions are satisfied to be able to apply the model. For example I want to find out how the the object density influences the number of missed selections. I'm using R and the lme4 package. Here is my model and the lines that generate the graphics.

```
model <- lmer(Misses ~ Density + (1|InteractionTechnique) + (1|UserID) + (1|Distance:ObjectSize), data = data_selection_all)
# Linearity of predictors
plot(resid(model),data_selection_all$Misses)
# Homogeneity of Variance
plot(model)
# Residuals normally distributed
qqnorm(resid(model))
qqline(resid(model))
```

[image: Linearity of predictors]
[image: Homogeneity of Variance]
[image: Residuals normally distributed]

As you can see, there are very strange distributions and the assumptions are not satisfied. This is probably due to the fact that in most cases a object was correctly selected at the first attempt and only in the more complex scenarios there were more misses. I tried a logarithmic transformation and a BoxCox transformation of the data but it did not help. Are linear mixed models not suitable here or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a [Binomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) outcome and not a normal one, i.e., the numbed of missed selection out of the number of total selection. Hence, it would be better to fit a mixed effects logistic regression and not a linear mixed model. That is something along these lines

```
model <- glmer(cbind(missed_selections, correct_selection) ~ Density + 
     (1 | InteractionTechnique) + (1 | UserID) + 
     (1 | Distance:ObjectSize), data = data_selection_all,
               family = binomial())
```

Moreover, you have a rather complicated random-effects structure. Are you certain you need all these random effects? Unless your data have very rich correlations, you may experience convergence problems fitting such a model.

Comment: Is it then correct to write `cbind(Misses, 1)` as there is always one successful selection and possibly multiple misses per task? Do have such generalized linear mixed models other assumptions than linear mixed models? How can I show that the assumptions are satisfied? As for the random effects: your are right, it should be possible to drop Distance and ObjectSize.

Comment: @Matthias if you have the number of failures before the first success, then this is a Geometric distribution (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). AFAIK, this is not available in **lme4**. If you would be willing to simplify your random effects structure, you could give a try to the **GLMMadaptive** package that allows you to program your own GLMM.